# Signature async. and synchronous methods

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, signature

if I have a method `Sub Foo(fooParam as String)` and I want to write the async version like

```
 Function FooAsync (fooParam as String) as Task
     Return Task.Run(Sub() Foo(fooParam))
 End Function
```

Now I need progress and cancellation, so I need to change the signature to

```
Function FooAsync (fooParam as String, progress as IProgress(of String), cancellationToken as CancellationToken) as Task
     Return Task.Run(Sub() Foo(fooParam))
 End Function
```

Microsoft says the async version should have the same signature as the synchronous one, so what are best-practice here or did I understand it wrong?

Passing progress and cancellationToken to a synch. method appears senseless for me...but only so I am able to just wrap the sync. method and return it as task.

For better understanding here the code, about how Im doing now. In Async have just written the sync method adding the progress and cancellation calls. But I'm sure this is not the way I should do this:

```
Public Sub DoCalibration(calibrationHoldTimeForReading As Integer)
    If Not PressureCalibrator.SerialPort.IsOpen() Then
        PressureCalibrator.SerialPort.Open()
    End If
    PressureCalibrator.PressureUnit = PressureUnit.bar
    For Each point In InputList
        SetMessPointAndMeasure(point, calibrationHoldTimeForReading)
    Next
    PressureCalibrator.Vent()
    PressureCalibrator.SerialPort.Close()
    Log.WriteLog("Calibration completed.")
End Sub


Public Function DoCalibrationAsync(calibrationHoldTimeForReading As Integer, Optional progress As IProgress(Of CalibrationStepResult) = Nothing, Optional cancellationToken As CancellationToken = Nothing) As Task 
     Return Task.Run((Sub()
                        If Not PressureCalibrator.SerialPort.IsOpen() Then
                            PressureCalibrator.SerialPort.Open()
                        End If
                        PressureCalibrator.PressureUnit = PressureUnit.bar
                        For Each point In InputList
                            Dim measureResult = SetMessPointAndMeasure(point, calibrationHoldTimeForReading)
                            If Not IsNothing(cancellationToken) Then  
                            CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                            End If
                            If Not IsNothing(progress) Then
                                progress.Report(measureResult)
                            End If
                        Next
                        PressureCalibrator.Vent()
                        PressureCalibrator.SerialPort.Close()
                        Log.WriteLog("Calibration completed.")
                    End Sub), cancellationToken)
End Function
```

Comment: Microsoft also says you shouldn't fake async over sync just by using Task.Run. Have a look at TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PauloMorgado. Could you explain what dou you mean with faking async over sync? Could you show me a little example how you would refactor my code? I was reading a lot about TaskCompletiionSource, but to be honest, I don't understand the purpose very good...

Comment: Start with http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/

Comment: Thanks @PauloMorgado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PauloMorgado I was able to understand the guidelines here by reading the articles he posted, and other related to them.